# Is it possible to make the compiler see VC name as VC type?

Tags: swift

I'm trying the make a function that receives a name (String) of a View Controller and then presents that View Controller modally. Example:

```
func presentViewControllerModally(newViewControllerName: String){

        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(newViewControllerName)_Identifier") as! newViewControllerName
     self.present(newViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

But I can't make the casting `as! newViewControllerName` to work as if the `newViewControllerName` is a type (and not an object of type String).

Comment: I believe you don't need `"Int"` string, etc. at all. Provide some code code of your exact usage.

Comment: I think this is a case when you have to tell us what you are really trying to do. The question as asked doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Hi @JeremyP, I'm trying to make a function that takes a name of specific ViewController (for example, "VC1") and that modally presents that ViewController. I was hoping to do it as so: storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(newViewControllerName)_Identifier") as! newViewControllerName

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing (using an `as`) wouldn't work, but more importantly, even if it did, it'd be useless.

Let's imagine it did work, and that you could write a line of code like:

```
let myValue: Any = functionThatReturnsAnAny()
let myType: String = functionThatReturnsAString()
let castedValue = myValue as! myType
```

Now what? What could you possibly do with `castedValue`? You don't know what type it is. There are no methods you could call. There's nothing you could pass it to. How is `castedValue` in any way different than `myValue`, other than you've created a new way your program can crash. (When you find yourself using `as!`, you've often gone down the wrong road in Swift. There are a few times it's necessary or appropriate, but they're very rare.)

Forget Strings for a moment and take this up a level. Let's say you just wanted to return a real (but unknown at compile-time) type?

```
let myValue: Any = functionThatReturnsAnAny()
let myType: Any.Type = functionThatReturnsAType()
let castedValue = myValue as! myType
```

This *still* doesn't make any sense. You have no information about `castedValue` that you didn't already have about `myValue`.

Types don't exist for their own sake. They exist to tell us what can be done with a value; what methods it has and what functions it can be passed to. That only makes sense if you actually are going to write code that uses those facts, which means you already need to know what type or types you expect. If you know what type or types you expect, then as others have answered, the correct approach is a `switch` or `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it’s quite easier than you think.

Instead of “casting” the string to the type, you can have a `switch` or an `if else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure casting is a good idea (or even possible)... Maybe something like

```
let myType = "Int"
if myType == "Int" { 
    return Int.self 
}
```

would work. Otherwise you could create an enum :

```
enum TypesToCheck: String {
    case int = "Int"
    case string = "String"
    ...
}

let myString = "Int"
let myType = TypesToCheck(rawValue: myString)!
switch myType {
    case .int:
        print(Int.self)
    case .string:
        print(String.self)
}
```

Please note that the force unwrapping isn't a good solution, I'm just making an example here.

Hope it helps